# Terraform.tfvars file not considered when calling local module in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have parent directory from there i am calling local module ,but Terraform.tfvars file present in parent directory not considered when calling local module .Its taking values from variable file present in local module.

my code is available in GitHub. My code is working fine except that its not considering terraform.tfvars file. Can anyone let me know what is issue in this code ?

https://github.com/sammouse/terraform-code.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its taking values from variable file present in local module.

That's how it works. There is **no inheritance** of variables in TF. You have to explicitly pass all the variables in parent module when to the child module. Otherwise, you have to copy-and-paste all veriables in tfvars in parent module, to tfvars file in child module.

Comment: it didn't take values from child module tfvars file as well. checked it. I know we can pass required variables inside module block. 
I thought if they are present in single tfvars file it should be better to change them when required.

Comment: @sam it only takes files from folder where you execute terraform command. So it's only parent module.

Comment: Took sometime to understand this concept.
I need to treat the local module in the same way as terraform registry module. In my parent module i am passing variables when calling the child module and making use of terraform.tfvars as well. Updated my git repo now.
 https://github.com/sammouse/terraform-code.git